# How to click the login button if it is written under span tag only with no extra added element in it

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0aen.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta3Sv.png) login

I tried with Css and xpath but it is not working.

How can i write the selenium webdriver code for this span tag because I wanted to click on login button.

Comment: Maybe a bit more context would be helpful. Do you have an example of the code and  which URL you're trying to reach? Screenshots would be helpful as well if possible.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot please have a look once and I want to click on login button which is under Span tag

Comment: @PrabhakarSingh- If you need help from the community here, you need to improve your question. Start by sharing the code you have tried so far, share the error you are getting. Share the code and error in the form of text, not image. Refer this - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Actually, shawn I am not getting any error while executing the script in the console but what I m trying to say is that I am not able to click on login button which is defined in span tag or which is defined under span tag.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("details-button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("proceed-link")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("userID")).sendKeys("ACSOW");
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Test@12345");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//span[class='common_btn fzp8']")).click(); Last one is the script which i have wrote down to click on Login button which is under span tag due to this I am not able to move forward in next web page.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any concern @shawn and thanks a lot for helping ,me

Comment: I just wanted to click on login button only after that I will move ahead and write the script for other web pages after login into that web application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Login']")).click();
```